# iphone controllers interactions

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller

Im starting with iPhone programming and objective c, i got some books and some tutorials to start with but i got one doubt and i cant find the answer for it.

I love mvc, so i have the view, the controller that interact with view and the model. 
But, do i have a main controller that interact with other controller?

for example, i have personaController, personView and person class as part of model. 
I have other mode class like familly, with a famillyView and do i need famillyController class ? should i put all in one main controller class?

if i should have more than one controller (one for each model class), how they interact? For example, i show famillyview, and want to show data from one person, so need personController right? should i got to one main controller and from that one to personController?

a pic to show my point of view. [enter link description here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/850/unledcjs.png/)

I hope its get clear my doubt. If someone know some rly good book or tutorial i appreciate it. Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used this [example](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-other-objects.html)
to interact with controllers.

Answer (score 0):

iOS programming uses Model/View/ViewController perception.

Models -> the classes that contains the guts and data of your application, like you mentioned. Person/Family and those sort of classes.

Views -> all the UI forms in iOS inherit from this class. a View is not a screen, it's an object that is contained in a screen.

ViewControllers -> you can refer ViewControllers to screens, each of them contain one main rootview that can contain multiple views, and those view can contain more subview and so on.

Comment: how do i interact between controllers? in android workd this would be activities and i have intent for that, just like method like startActivityForResult

Comment: UIViewController *vc = [[SomeUIViewController alloc] initWithSomething...]; then you can present the view controller inside another one's code like this: [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES]; //It's that simple